Need all cause of moderation be specified in ToS due to EU DSA rule?
I had the impression reading articles about Digital Service Act, that a service provider need to specify in ToS all the reasons that will lead to ban or other moderation activities (like censoring a post).
Otherwise the banned/censored party may contest that the ban is unfair and cause a damage to his right of free expression.
Here what give to me that idea:

Services Act (DSA)

Providers of intermediary services shall include information on any restrictions that they impose in relation to the use of their service in respect of information provided by the recipients of the service, in their terms and conditions. That information shall include information on any policies, procedures, measures and tools used for the purpose of content moderation, including algorithmic decision-making and human review, as well as the rules of procedure of their internal complaint handling system. It shall be set out in clear, plain, intelligible, user-friendly and unambiguous language, and shall be publicly available in an easily accessible and machine-readable format.




Providers of intermediary services shall act in a diligent, objective and proportionate manner in applying and enforcing the restrictions referred to in paragraph 1, with due regard to the rights and legitimate interests of all parties involved, including the fundamental rights of the recipients of the service, such as the freedom of expression, freedom and pluralism of the media, and other fundamental rights and freedoms as enshrined in the Charter.


My question is, is it really necessary state in ToS a list of all reasons that may lead to an user ban/exclusion? If yes how detailed/complete such list have to be?

Reading through the definitions in article 3 of regulation 2022/2065, I get the impression that things like Facebook/Twitter fall under (i) "online platforms", not (g) "intermediary services". If so, the quoted text (from article 14) would apply to things like Cloudflare, Dropbox, ISPs etc. which do not do much "moderation" in the usual sense of the term. (I will not post this guess as an answer, because I lack familiarity with that area of law, and I might well be mistaken.)

@UJM good point, now I am more puzzled by the fact that some sources also include social networks among them (https://www.insideprivacy.com/digital-services-act/digital-services-acts-impact-on-terms-of-service/). And social networks that are also VLOPs seems to comply to that regulation (now I don't know if because social networks or VLOP)
